# Is it possible to inject an event within my service to other apps without root?

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I'm making an android application that will inject touch events based on motions that I make. So far, I can use instrumentations to inject events but only within my application. I want to be able to use this service in other apps as well. I've read that this is possible with root but is there a way without it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from a platform signed application/service to inject the keys/events to other applications. But I suppose the platform signatures change for different manufacturers !!

Comment: Do you know how to make my app platform signed? I read that I would need to obtain the signature from the root of android source tree but I'm unsure how to do this. And by different manufacturers, do you mean phone manufacturers?

Comment: you need to have the keystore or platform certificate of the phone's OEM to sign the app to have platform defined privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I went to the android source project and got the .pk8 and .509.pem from my android os, which is marshmallow, and created a keystore using them. However, the signed apk that I created using this keystore still gives me the same error as before. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.  And the reason for this is security.  If you could do that, you could screw up or access all sorts of data in the other apps.  They try to avoid that.